# How to run eject in my react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to eject my react app,so I use code:`npm run eject` in cmmand line.But it told me I failed.And these are all logs:

```
Remove untracked files, stash or commit any changes, and try again.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todoevents@0.1.0 eject: `react-scripts eject`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the todoevents@0.1.0 eject script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pigpigever\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-
14T09_03_14_398Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone tell me how to do ?

Comment: `Remove untracked files, stash or commit any changes`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That error message isn't massively clear ([in fact, there's an open issue on GitHub to improve it](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/pull/2090)).

`create-react-app` [prevents you from ejecting your app without first having committed any outstanding changes to Git](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/pull/2090) - this is so that if ejecting breaks things (or if you just decide you've made a mistake and want to go back), you're able to restore your project to how it was before.

As the error message says - to get the command to work, you'll need to:

- Add any untracked files you want to keep to your Git repository.
- Remove any untracked files you don't want to keep (either by deleting them or adding them to your `.gitignore`).
- Commit your changes, or stash them if you'd like to commit them at a later time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
git add .
git commit -am "Save before ejecting"
```

And try it again

Answer (score 1):

- In the base directory do:

```sh
git init
```

- go inside the react folder ,then do

```sh
git add .
```

- then commit it

```sh
git commit -m "some msg"
```

- then

```sh
yarn eject
```

or

```sh
npm run eject
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use 'create-react-app', it prevents you from ejecting your app without first having committed any outstanding changes to Git. That is the sole reason for the error.
Go to your github account create a repository, clone it to your base system . then use 'npm-run-eject'.
Mine worked with this.
I hope your problem gets resolved too :)

## HAPPY_CODING

Answer (score 0):

Please commit all the changes you have done and then retry to eject using the command - 'npm run eject'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did the following to fix it.

```
rm -rf .gitignore
rm -rf .git
```

finally

```
npm run eject
```

Ejected successfully! :)

Comment: That is assuming you want to blow away all git associations with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these steps:

1. **git add .**
2. You must have to commit before install eject:
   **git commit -m "save before ejecting"**
3. run eject:
   if you use yarn, you should type this on your terminal:
   **yarn eject**
   or
   **npm run eject**
4. one config folder will be added to your project, and inside this folder, you will find one file called **"webpack.config.js".**
   searching "css-loader" or type (Ctrl+f) for searching specific words.
   you will find below code in this file.

   ```js
   {
      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
      options: cssOptions,      
   }
   ```

**change it by:**

```
{
   loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
   options: {
      modules: {
        mode: "local",
        localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]"
      },
      import: true,
      importLoaders: true
    }     
}
```

5. **the most important part is now you must restart your code editor, sometimes it can be 4/5 times.**

The above steps worked for me.
Hopefully, it will also work for you.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

m ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path /home/red/Desktop/react-course/package.json

npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/red/Desktop/react-course/package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

If someone facing this issue then just do this:-

cd your project name    *(for e.g react-assignment)*

npm run eject

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Please consider giving some explanation about the cause of the problem and how your answer solves it. It seems it is an older question and was already answered. Please also explain how your solution is better or the old one fails (if it does).